# How to add Windows Group-based authentication to an ASP.NET Core 7.0 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

I have created a new ASP.NET Core 7 MVC web application in VS 2022.  I added Windows authentication during the project creation, which added the following to `Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();
```

Then in the `Index` action of the `HomeController`, I added an `Authorize` attribute:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"LOCAL-WORKSTATION\AuthTestGroup")]
public IActionResult Index() 
{
    return View();
}
```

And I created the `AuthTestGroup` Windows group on my workstation (not domain-joined, if that matters). I also added my user to this group.

When I run the project I get an HTTP 403 error.

If I remove the `[Authorize]` attribute, I see the `/Home/Index` view.

How can I add Windows Group authorization when using Windows authentication in my ASP.NET Core 7.0 application?

Comment: You need an auth provider for anything core or above. If you use AD, you can easily add claims to the token with a custom policy inside a B2C tenant.

Comment: @GHDevOps - any thoughts on adding an answer with the steps needed to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Windows doesn't update the security descriptor of the logged in user when you change their group membership until the next time they log in.  A reboot solved my problem.